# Android WebView font size in pixels

Tags: android, fonts, webview

I'd like to set the font size I'm using in a WebView to a specific pixel size. I'm doing something along the lines of

```
<p style="font-size: 18px">Text</p>
```

However, the size of the font is different on different devices. Any idea how to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: because different devices have different sized pixels... If you actually want to set it to pixels you should be expecting this variation across devices. Do you have a specific reason for wanting to use pixels?

Comment: sorry, maybe i should've elaborated on this. i use pixels, but i scale the pixels to match the device's dpi. my client has a fixed pixel design that i scale to the maximum possible size (with borders top bottom or left right). everything works perfectly except for the webview.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution I found was adding the following meta tag to the HTML

```
 <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"target-densitydpi=device-dpi\" />
```

Comment: Deprecated http://www.petelepage.com/blog/2013/02/viewport-target-densitydpi-support-is-being-deprecated/

Comment: thanks for letting us know. i should look into an alternate way then.

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">  worked fine for me as commented in the link below.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the webview to get a settings object and [`setDefaultFontSize(int size)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setDefaultFontSize(int)) method to set the default font size.

for example:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(20);
```

Alternatively,
You can use [`setInitialScale(int percentage)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setInitialScale(int)) method on your web view to set the percentage zoom you need, you can try it with different percentages and see which one you like.

for example:

```
myWebView.setInitialScale(85);
```

You can also use the webview to get it's settings object and then use [`setBuiltInZoomControls(boolean value)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setBuiltInZoomControls(boolean)) method to allow/disallow the user to use the default zoom controls so they can zoom according to their preference.

for example:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

None of that was working for me, I needed to do this instead:

```
WebSettings settings = wv.getSettings();
if (Utils.hasIceCreamSandwich())
    settings.setTextZoom( (int)(settings.getTextZoom() * 1.2));
else {
    settings.setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.LARGER);
}
```